# Comparing Two String List Elements

Tags: java, list

I'm working on a game in Java and I need to compare the first character an element in a list with another character of an element in a separate list, as an if statement. What would be the best way to do that?

So far I have:

```
if((user.get(0)).equals(pack.get(0)))
```

I'm just not sure how to at the .charAt() to this.

Comment: please post your code that you have already tried

Comment: Do you need to compare every element in the list with all others?

Comment: The question is a little vague, do you want compare each element in the first list with each element in the second list or do you just want to do a positional comparison (ie compare element `n` in the first list with element `n` in the second list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
list1.add("ant");
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
list2.add("apple");
list2.add("bear");
//comparing 'a' from "ant" from list1 with 'a' from "apple" from list2
System.out.println(list1.get(0).charAt(0) == list2.get(0).charAt(0)); //true
//comparing 'a' from "ant" from list1 with 'b' from "bear" from list2
System.out.println(list1.get(0).charAt(0) == list2.get(1).charAt(0)); //false
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to compare every element in the list with all others you could try this:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
  for(int j = i + 1; j < list.size(); j++) {
    if(list.get(i).charAt(0) == list.get(j).charAt(0)) {
      //code executed if true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `String.charAt()` would be more efficient.

Answer (score -1):

```
if ( string1.charAt(0) == string2.charAt(0) ){
   //Your code to handle the equality here
}
```

Comment: It's better to include some context/explanation with code as this makes the answer more useful for the OP and for future readers.